# ext:news with rx_shariff - mail link not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

TYPO3 v8.7.15, News 7.0.4 and rx_shariff 11.0.2

I've enabled three services that can be used to share my news detail pages (FB, Twitter & Mail).

This is my partial(Shariff.html):

```
<html xmlns:rx="http://typo3.org/ns/Reelworx/RxShariff/ViewHelper">
<rx:shariff data="{url: 'http://example.com/'}" services="facebook,twitter,mail" enableBackend="true" />
</html>
```

Both the FB and Twitter share buttons work fine, however when I test the Mail button I'm sent to

```
http://example.com/?view=mail
```

I've checked the documentation for both News and rx_shariff but can't see anything obvious.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<rx:shariff data="{url: url, title: newsTitle, mail-subject: 'Your mail subject', mail-body: 'The mail body', mail-url: 'mailto:{settings.shariff.mailto}'}" services="facebook,twitter,googleplus,mail" enableBackend="true" />
```

Comment: 1) The correct manual is here https://github.com/heiseonline/shariff/blob/develop/README.md
2) `settings.data.mail-url` has as default value `mailto:` to hint into the right direction
3) I currently do not see where your `settings.shariff.*` should come from

Comment: 1) Ok
2) As @Tom explained it doesn't work if you don't specify it.
3) From typoscript custom settings

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work for me, as the variables "url" and "newsTitle" are not are not passed on to the partial. Also, the subject and body should be dynamic. This worked for me:

In Templates Detail.html:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.detail.showSocialShareButtons}">
    <n:extensionLoaded extensionKey="rx_shariff">
        <f:render partial="Detail/Shariff" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem}"/>
    </n:extensionLoaded>
</f:if>
```

In Partials Detail/Shariff.html:

```
<div xmlns:n="http://typo3.org/ns/GeorgRinger/News/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:rx="http://typo3.org/ns/Reelworx/RxShariff/ViewHelper" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    {n:link(newsItem:newsItem, settings:settings, uriOnly:1, configuration:'{forceAbsoluteUrl:1}') -> f:variable(name: 'url')}
    <rx:shariff data="{url: url, title: newsItem.title, mail-url: 'mailto:'}" services="facebook,twitter,whatsapp,threema,mail" enableBackend="false" />
</div>
```

This will give you: mailto:?subject=[TitleOfTheNews]&body=[AbsoulteUrlToTheNews]